# change docker containers IP address

Tags: networking, docker

My network is on 10.0.0.0 when I start docker containers they have a different set of IP addresses (172.17.42.1)

How do I get my containers to start up on the same 10.0.0.0 network

I have configured br0 and for it to be static and I would like docker0 to share the same ip range so that it allocates ip address to containers on the same network

Comment: this helps me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/P93kOO7-QvA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this link will help you
**http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/**

In short, just add to **/etc/network/interfaces** the following:

```
auto docker0
iface docker0 inet static
    address 172.30.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports dummy0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

And restart the interface, or restart PC.

```
ifdown docker0
ifup docker0
```

Comment: When I got to step 3 "ip addr add 172.30.1.1/20 dev br0" adding my own ip range I got this error "Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "10.0.0.100/135"." Do you know how to resolve it

Comment: The value after the slash is a number of bits of netmask. There are not 135 bits in an IP address. Perhaps you meant /24 or /27? (Also, .100 is not a good base address for a subnet.)

Comment: pls do not only put links as answers

Comment: I have lots of existing docker containers from different users. Do I need to remove all the existing containers? Or I can just restart all the containers to make this change into effect?

Comment: and if container is centos ?!? and if container is ubuntu/debian WITHOUT those files/tools (interfaces, ifup, ifdown) ?!?

Answer (score 6):

Already accept answer isn't really an answer but just a link. So I will provide solution which works for me. Important to note that solution may get overwritten by docker upgrade. You should be asked about replacing your docker configuration on upgrading package.
Config path is valid as of Ubuntu 15.10.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/docker
```

add this line to file

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--bip=10.66.33.10/24"
```

then reboot
after reboot start a container

```
docker run -it --name t2 jangorecki/r-base-dev /bin/bash
```

and check ip of a container

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' t2
```

Comment: May be, it is better to suggest editing for accepted answer, then make repetition?

Comment: @Evedel please read the link from other answer before making judgements on similarity. This is a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

On my Centos container I do this:

```
docker exec -it c1 bash -c "echo -e 'IPADDR=172.17.0.4 \n HOSTNAME=c1' >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0; /etc/init.d/network restart";
```

Answer (score 0):

**REAL ANSWER** is the answer to this: ... AND IS WORKING, tested myself

[How to change the IP address of a docker after creating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088832/how-to-change-the-ip-address-of-a-docker-after-creating-it)

also answer marked as the solution ASSUMES that container is a certain distro (debian/ubuntu based) AND one installed a lot of network tools in it !
how was that with assumption is the mother of all ... -ups

Comment: I like the answer on the linked post, but would you replicate the important details from that answer to this post (leaving the link in place)? Having the data here keeps your answer useful even if something happens to the linked thread.