# How to change the IP address of a docker after creating it?

Tags: docker, networking, ip, bridge

I have a docker linked to a bridge with IP address `192.168.150.1/24`.
Once I create the docker instance from a docker image it gets an IP address, `192.168.150.2`, but according to my requirement, this IP address, `192.168.150.2`, must be reserved since I want to use it for some other thing.

Now, I want to change the IP address of this docker instance as `192.168.150.3`. Is it possible to do? if so how? Please, help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will have to first detach the container from the custom network and the connect it back by providing the ip.

You can follow the following steps :

1. `docker network disconnect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER`
2. `docker network connect --ip 192.168.150.3 NETWORK CONTAINER`

Comment: after running the second command: 

`Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets`

Comment: I have a container with MariaDB and another with a Drupal. The DB config for Drupal was using the IP for the MariaDB container but every once in a while the IP changes and the site crashes because it doesn't find the DB. I've followed your steps and they work like charm but, does this IP assignation remain in the docker config? I mean, will I have again the IP problem I described? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a particular IP address when you define the port mapping, for example

-p 192.168.150.3:6379:6379

Answer (score 0):

here is another option, try to use `-b bridge` option to use a certain ip range, like for instance `-b br0=192.168.150.3/24` 
here is more complete example [configure docker bridge network](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/)